# Vim: Search in Open Buffers

Tags: vim, file-search, findinfiles

One features I like with Visual Studio is the ability to search in open files only. For example, if I recently did changes to some files and I would like to trace those changes, I might search for a certain word, but only in those files to avoid getting a large list of necessary matches.

Is this possible with Vim?! What I am interested in is being able to open the files I have changed so for using:

```
gvim `git diff --name-only`
```

then search those files for what I want.

Comment: There are many ways to do that. Can you be a little more specific to the kind of output/result you are expecting?

Comment: I thought the message is clear. Say I have 5 open files. If I want to use vimgrep/grep to search those 5 files, I have to list them by name, which is quite long task. I want vimgrep/grep to search in opened files (i.e. buffers) only.

Comment: you can `:vim /pattern/ \`git diff --name-only\`` or `:bufdo :%s/ ...` or ...

Answer (score 2):

A nice way to do that is to use vim's internal grep command (`:vim`):

```
:vim /pattern/ `git diff --name-only`
:copen
```

This will open a small window (called `quickfix`) with the search results and links to open the corresponding files (they don't have to be open).

Answer (score 1):

If you want vim to open up all the files in their own buffers for files that match your diff, you could try this:

```
gvim $(grep -l pattern $(git diff --relative --name-only))
```

`git diff --relative --name-only` shows the changed files in the index but with filenames relative to the current working directory.

`grep -l pattern <list of files>` will report the filenames that contain a match on `pattern`. (Note that the pattern just has to exist in the files, *not* in the `git diff` output.)

POSIX `$()` instead of backticks makes using nested commands possible.

Comment: nested commands are possible with backticks also: `echo <bt>echo \<bt>echo abc\<bt><bt>` (replace <bt> with actual backticks).

Comment: @ZyX, ha, never thought to escape backticks to nest them before. :) Every day something new.